# Laravel Mailable queue, how to pass custom data to MessageSent event

Tags: php, laravel-mail, laravel-events

I am using Laravel Mailable to send email, and I want to log the email that was successfully sent.

Laravel Mailable have default event that was fired after the email was sent

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mail#events

So I hook my listener to this event

```
protected $listen = [
        'App\Events\Event' => [
            'App\Listeners\EventListener',
        ],
        'Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSent' => [
            'App\Listeners\LogSentEmailNotification',
        ],
    ];
```

Listener handler

```
public function handle(MessageSent $event)
{

    //get extra data 
    $job_request_id = $event->message->job_request_id;

    $message = $event->message;

    $data = [
        'job_request_id' => $job_request_id,
        'to' => $message->getHeaders()->get('To'),
        'from' => $message->getHeaders()->get('From'),
        'cc' => $message->getHeaders()->get('Cc'),
        'bcc' => $message->getHeaders()->get('Bcc'),
        'subject' => $message->getHeaders()->get('Subject')->getFieldBody(),
        'body' => $message->getBody(),
    ];

    $email_notification_log = $this->email_notification_log->create($data);
}
```

The extra data job_request_id is passed from the build() method in Mailable class, CustomEmailNotification.php

```
class CustomEmailNotification extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue
{

    public function build()
    {
        $job_request_id = 1;

        //pass extra data mail message            

        $this->withSwiftMessage(function ($message) use($job_request_id){
            $message->job_request_id = $job_request_id;
        });
    }
}
```

Right now this line on Listener class is working fine without queue, however when using queue it will return null

```
 //get extra data 
 $job_request_id = $event->message->job_request_id;
 var_dump($job_request_id);
 //null when using queue
```

Question is, what is the correct way to pass custom data to MailSent event when using queue?

Or is there possibility job_request_id is lost when using queue and pass to withSwiftMessage(), so the Event Listener just received null value?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Any `public` properties on the Mailable are saved to the `data` attribute in the event.

```
class CustomEmailNotification extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue
{
    public $job_request_id = 1;
}
```

now in your listener you can get the property name as an array index of `data`

```
var_dump($event->data['job_request_id']);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Supervisor as queue worker. Try restarting all the process. Supervisor must be reloaded to reflect the recent changes from your code.

```
sudo supervisorctl restart all
```

Answer (score 0):

Mabey this could help you
https://medium.com/@guysmilez/queuing-mailables-with-custom-headers-in-laravel-5-4-ab615f022f17

According to this post, the variables are lost when you put the mailable into a queue, so you have to override the send method of Mailable